# Get data and store it in PHP variable to update other tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help :) I'm a beginner and I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I need to update 2 tables with data from a csv file.
The csv has 3 columns : Reference, price and quantity.

1) 1st SQL table to update is easy. The table has 4 columns:
Id product, price, quantity, and **reference** (refence that is the same as in the csv file)

```
$mysqlquery.="UPDATE  ps_product SET  quantity = ".$data[2].", price = ".$data[3]." WHERE  reference = '".$data[1]."';";
```

2) I then need to update a second table but the reference column is missing.
The other table has 3 columns : ID, price, quantity.

How can I store the ID attached to the reference to update the second table?

Any help will be so welcome!

Thanks

---- UPDATE --- 
Sorry if I wasn't clear.
I found a solution : INNER JOIN

```
$mysqlquery.="UPDATE ps_stock_available AS s
                INNER JOIN ps_product_shop AS ps ON ps.id_product = s.id_product
                INNER JOIN ps_product AS p ON p.id_product = ps.id_product
                SET s.quantity = ".$data[2].", ps.price=".$data[3]." WHERE p.reference = '".$data[1]."';";
```

Comment: Can you take time to re-edit your answer?  Your question is so vague that I am still clueless after reading it twice. You already have your reference when updating the first table. Should you not use it?

Comment: I encourage you to use prepared statements to avoid sql injection attacks

Comment: Thanks for your anwsers. KarelG, I edited my question, is it clearer for you?

Comment: @TarangP How is last insert id going to be any help when the OP has done an UPDATE and not an INSERT

Comment: As you are using `reference = '".$data[1]."'` to update this table... is not the `$data[1]` value the id you are wanting to use on the other table???

Comment: I use the reference to update my 1st table. The reference is in my csv file and my first table.

Comment: I have no ID in my csv file.

Comment: and no reference in my second table

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful if you'd shown us the FULL structure of the tables. If I've understood you correctly then you are saying ps_product.reference is the natural primary key for the table, but has a surrogate key which is referenced by second_table.id.

You didn't tell us what attribute in ps_product is referenced by second_table.id. You didn't tell us what the second table is called.

Using surrogate keys when you have a natural key is very bad programming practice. Naming a non-unique key as "id" is bad programming practice. Storing the same data in multiple places within a relational database is very, **VERY** bad programming practice.

And you are starting to learn why.

The best advice anyone can give you is to kill this monstrosity now and start again from scratch. But no doubt you think its just a bit of pain now and everything will be rosy in the future. It won't be. You will spiral into a pit of hell from which there is no escape.

You can do an update on a JOIN but this is an ugly hack to work around serious design flaws:

```
UPDATE second_table st JOIN product_ps ps
  ON st.id=ps.id
SET st.quantity = ".$data[2].", st.price = ".$data[3]."
WHERE ps.reference = '".$data[1]
```

But since the values are *in* the product_ps table....

```
UPDATE second_table st JOIN product_ps ps
  ON st.id=ps.id
SET st.quantity = ps.price, st.price = st.quantity
WHERE ps.reference = '".$data[1]
```

I presume you completely trust the source and integrity of the CSV file you are processing. If not then it will kill your database for you unless yo add some validation around the content.